# InnerBlocks templateLock="all" issue on WordPress 6.1.1

Tags: wordpress, block, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a custom block that creates a 3 column template with `InnerBlocks` and a `templateLock="all"` attribute to avoid that users move/remove or add something in the template. It used to properly work on WordPress 6.0.3 (and bellow) but then when I updated to 6.1.1 it had issues. Instead of locking the template and showing the columns in which I should be able to add other blocks, it hides the newly inserted columns so that they are unselectable in the editor.

Here is how I create the innerBlocks

```
<window.wp.blockEditor.InnerBlocks
    template={new Array(3).fill(['core/column', {}])}
    templateLock="all"
/>
```

Here is what I have when I copy the block

```
<!-- wp:attest/grid-columns {"numColumnsStr":"3"} -->
<div class="grid grid--columns-3"><!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"></div>
<!-- /wp:column --></div>
<!-- /wp:attest/grid-columns -->
```

I've tried to look at the changes since WordPress 6.0.3 but couldn't find something useful.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I would install an older version, and check if it actually was working before. Because it looks like your code generally is correct.

Comment: Thank you @Frizzant Do you mean an older version of WordPress? If so, I did downgrade to WP v6.0.3 and it works.

Comment: yes that is what I mean. That is quite special in that case. To my knowledge, `templateLock="all"` does stil work on the current 6.x version.
Is it possible that something else breaks your code?

Comment: I think I figured it out. In fact the columns are there, they are just locked (and so their child blocks). What I did was set `templateLock`, `move` and `remove` to false for all newly inserted columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact child blocks inherits from parent's `templateLock` attribute so the columns were present, they were just locked and as they are newly inserted, they were empty thus rendered invisible. So the idea is to unlock the `core/column` block and its (future) child blocks by default. Here is my updated code

```
<window.wp.editor.InnerBlocks
    template={new Array(numColumns).fill(['core/column', {templateLock: false, lock: {move: false, remove: false}}])}
    templateLock='all'
/>
```